# Session-only memtable updates / merges in RocksDB

Tags: nosql, rocksdb

RocksDB newbie here.

In runtime, I only use RocksDB to **read** the data. Sometimes, I need to merge session-specific records from other sources.

I don't want them to be merged into the main database. 
I want them to exist only during the session lifetime for that specific session.

I can, of course, use a regular std::vector or something and merge the RocksDB and the other sources, but that would duplicate the data.

I see a bunch of concepts like memtable and merge, which sound like they might be used or exploited. For example, if I can tell memtable to never commit, and just abandon the changes, that should work. Is it doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to separate them into different [column families](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Column-Families), and just dropping the one you don't want to persist, when you shut down your application. If you need per-entry lifetime, you will probably have to consider something custom like a RAII-holder class, if you are using c++, which inserts on construction and deletes on destruction. I would still go with a separate column family to have the data cleanly separated, in case of a crash-failure.

Comment: Thanks, @midor. Actually, I meant adding "rows", not "columns" - and they will be from other databases. Does your advice still work in this case?

Comment: I got that, but what you were planning to do would kind of mess with the implementation. Considering that you only need to read, you could of course also restore the database from a backup and then just manipulate it, and drop the database when you shut down. On the next start you load the backup again, and nothing has changed. The downside is that you absolutely can't manipulate the original data while online.

Comment: Thanks again. Meh :) . I guess I'll just mix these two in memory.